# Changing Columns in VBA across multiple formulas based on date

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below generated from the Macro Recorder.  I want to update the column reference in several formulas, however when I started with the first one it keeps erroring out. I'm obtaining the current Month with the input box.  I need to subtract 4 from the C below resulting in -1, then add the value of Mon_Num. Resulting in the correct column reference.

Can anyone help me make this dynamic so that I can update the remaining formulas in my series?

Dim Prior_Month As Date
Dim Mon_Num As Integer

Prior_Month = Application.InputBox("Please input last day of Fiscal Period", "Period End", "Enter Date")

Mon_Num = Month(Prior_Month)

```
Range("F6:F7").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+FORECAST!R[79]C[3]/1000"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to add the value in Mon_num to negative one (-1) and integrate that as the column value in the formula.  If so, just change the last line of your code to be as follows:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+FORECAST!R[79]C[" & Mon_num - 1 & "]/1000"
```

If I have misunderstood what you are trying to accomplish, please clarify in a comment below.

Comment: I think that is close.. Let me be more clear. 

The macro recorded the 3 for my column, however I am trying to make it so this will work for any month of the year, so I want to start with a value of -1 for C( 4 columns to the left), then add the value of Mon_Num . I'm not sure how to get the C value to start at -1.

Comment: I dimmed a variable for C, as integer. Set it to -4, then put this for my formula. I think this maybe the cleanest way to do this for all of the formulas I'm changing since all the C have diff values to start.

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+FORECAST!R[79]C[" & Mon_Num + Act_c & "]/1000"

Comment: It would be helpful if you could specify what varies in the different places you are trying to use this code.  Clearly, Mon_num changes (because you are getting it from the user).  But it seems that the result calculated needs to be different depending on which cell is active when the code is run too.  If so, that is the part missing from your problem statement.  Try giving a few examples, such as

When Mon_num is 4 and the cell is in column 5, the formula inserted should be 

"=+FORECAST!R[79]C[2]/1000"

Giving several of these statements should do the trick so I can help